# Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.launcher

Tags: java, apache, ant

I am using Windows 7. I have downloaded Apache ant to C:/Program Files

1. Here is my ANT_HOME: `C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4`
2. Here is my JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`
3. Here is my part of path: `C:\Program
       Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin;C:\Program Files
       (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin`

I also checked that `ant-launcher.jar` is under `/lib` directory,
and I get the error in the title.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some weird reason, ant does not work if your ANT_HOME has spaces in it. Put it in a path without any spaces, it should work. Also try putting your java in a path without spaces.

Comment: Note that you can escape spaces in the path (works on OSX) e.g. `export ANT_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/lib/ant`

Answer (score 1):

There is another workaround for you, if you don't want to change the ant path.
Just change the env variable path with C:\Progra~1\apache.... and if your files are placed in program files(x86) then instead of Progra~1 , write Progra~2.

But it's advisable to keep them in a path, with no space in the folder's name